# MongoId and bson_ext problem: no such file to load -- bson_ext

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

There is a similar question about 'bson_ext', but it's not work for me.

[MongoMapper and bson_ext problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900604/mongomapper-and-bson-ext-problem)

I'm using Rails 2.3.8 + MongoId 1.9.1. I followed the "[installation](http://mongoid.org/docs/installation/)" page as:

```
gem install mongoid
gem install mongo -v=1.0.4
gem install bson_ext -v=1.0.4
```

In my config/environment.rb, I added:

```
config.gem 'mongoid'
config.gem 'mongo', :version=>'1.0.4'
config.gem 'bson_ext', :verstion=>'1.0.4'
```

When I start the application with `ruby script/server`, it shows:

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 2.3.8 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
no such file to load -- bson_ext
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
...
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
script/server:3
Missing these required gems:
  bson_ext  = 1.0.4

You're running:
  ruby 1.8.7.299 at /usr/local/bin/ruby
  rubygems 1.3.7 at /root/.gem/ruby/1.8, /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8

Run `rake gems:install` to install the missing gems.
```

But I have installed `bson_ext 1.0.4`:

```
gem list

bson (1.0.4, 1.0.3, 1.0.1, 1.0)
bson_ext (1.0.4, 1.0.1, 1.0)
mongo (1.0.4, 1.0.1, 1.0)
mongoid (1.9.1)
mongo_ext (0.19.3)
```

And, I have tried to use 1.0 and 1.0.1, but the same exceptions are thrown.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your config.gem line to:

```
config.gem 'bson_ext', :version=>'1.0.4', :lib => false
```

This prevents rails from trying to require "bson_ext", which doesn't work.  The bson gem actually tries to require "bson_ext/cbson" automatically, and eventually falls back to bson_ruby if it can't find a native version.

Answer (score 0):

I had to uninstall all the bson and mongo gems and then run `rake gems:install` with only:

```
  config.gem "mongo_mapper"
```

in my `environment.rb` file. The Railscasts for [MongoDB and MongoMapper](http://railscasts.com/episodes/194-mongodb-and-mongomapper) helped me get started using MongoDB with my Rails 2.3.8 app. Anything else would generate the bson_ext error.

Comment: So you're running without the bson_ext lib?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I'll try a fresh install with only "config.gem 'mongoid'" on my next instance to confirm this.